# Android threads and service stops without notice

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

So I've made an app that uses a lot of threads/Runnable (we're talking 300+) to download a lot of content. This works fine on emulator and some devices like the Samsung Galaxy S3 but for some reason on HTC One and other devices my threads or services are stopped without any notice, warning, error. The app continues to run but whatever service/thread that starts all the threads is just terminated.

What I've tryed:

- Using ExecutorService (thread pool) starting and managing all thread
- Start threads in AsyncTask with ExecutorService
- Start threads in bound Service with ExecutorService
- Start threads in service START_STICKY and startForeground

Logcat from HTC One with START_STICKY and startForeground (just saved data called POI, starting downloading number 26 then stops):

```
05-23 14:52:54.732: D/libc(17514): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 13(0x6170692e706172),sn(),family 0,flags 4
05-23 14:52:54.732: D/libc(17514): [NET] getaddrinfo-,err=8
05-23 14:52:55.363: D/historie(17514): save POI id: jtyvZD9bX9
05-23 14:52:55.383: D/historie(17514): Starting poi number: 26
05-23 14:52:57.595: D/WifiStateMachine(705): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -65 abnormalRssiCnt = 0 newLinkSpeed = 72
05-23 14:52:57.595: D/WifiStateMachine(705): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative mLinkspeedCount = 1, mLinkspeedSum: 72
05-23 14:52:59.998: D/PMS(705): acquireWL(4237bc08): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  AlarmManager 0x1 705 1000
05-23 14:53:00.028: D/PMS(705): releaseWL(4237bc08): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  AlarmManager 0x1
05-23 14:53:00.048: I/ClockThread(996): now=1400849580059 next=59941
05-23 14:53:00.068: W/MastheadClock(1546): mDigitAnimMin.start
05-23 14:53:00.608: D/WifiStateMachine(705): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -65 abnormalRssiCnt = 0 newLinkSpeed = 72
05-23 14:53:00.608: D/WifiStateMachine(705): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative mLinkspeedCount = 2, mLinkspeedSum: 144
05-23 14:53:03.642: D/WifiStateMachine(705): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -65 abnormalRssiCnt = 0 newLinkSpeed = 72
05-23 14:53:03.642: D/WifiStateMachine(705): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative mLinkspeedCount = 3, mLinkspeedSum: 216
05-23 14:53:06.675: D/WifiStateMachine(705): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -64 abnormalRssiCnt = 0 newLinkSpeed = 72
05-23 14:53:06.675: D/WifiStateMachine(705): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative mLinkspeedCount = 4, mLinkspeedSum: 288
05-23 14:53:09.698: D/WifiStateMachine(705): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -64 abnormalRssiCnt = 0 newLinkSpeed = 72
05-23 14:53:09.698: D/WifiStateMachine(705): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative mLinkspeedCount = 5, mLinkspeedSum: 360
05-23 14:53:09.698: D/WifiStateMachine(705): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative: Update RSSI:-64 and linkspeed:72 in database
05-23 14:53:09.698: D/WifiApDatabaseHandler(705): updateConnectedAP...
```

**Edit 1**:

So calling the GC on manually makes me able to download more data whereafter it stops again, So I could hack it around by calling the GC each time I download new data. This is my current implementation, but why do the finished threads take up memory? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: 300+ threads? Seriously...why would you do that?

Comment: @Squonk It's in a thread pool, so to be more correct, 1-2 thread run many times over...

Comment: "The app continues to run" -- how have you determined this? Most likely, your process is being terminated.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes the process is terminated, but if I have an asynctask that downloads content I can still pan around click buttons and navigate in the app, just without data. If in service the service is not killed it just stops and sometimes resumes again.

Comment: try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318943/stopping-service-results-in-orphaned-thread?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @mani345 not quite usefull. I want it to continue not stop.

Comment: If you only have 1-2 threads continually being run over and over again, the GC probably won't clean it up correctly, since an object only gets cleaned up when all references to it have been released. It might be worth having a look in to [different types of references.](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2006/05/understanding_w.html)

Comment: HTC One has a developer mode (activated by multiple taps onto Settings > About > Software information > More.. where you touch Build number), have you tried playing around with the various settings such as limit background processes and such (maybe this is active on the device?)? Barring that it sounds like the HTC device has less memory than your Samsung and the system is shutting down the background processes sooner...

Comment: @Arcshade that shouldn't be an issue here since calling System.gc() manually solves the problem.

Comment: @LeoK I haven't played around with it no. But I want it to work without any extra settings enabled.

Comment: @Warpzit I was thinking maybe it was already enabled on the device and limiting it. However it's more likely that you're just using too much memory/proc. for a background app and the device has less of it to spare. Have you tried using a resource monitoring app and compare the two device's performance with your app running in the background...?

Comment: @LeoK not yet, but I've come to the same conclusion = memory is an issue. There is several other problems with this app, just hope I can make it bareable.

Comment: Have you considered using IntentService? It is only one thread, but is always run in background. And, are you acquiring wakelock during download?

Comment: @rootkit did you actually read what I tryed? "Start threads in service START_STICKY and startForeground"

Comment: I did. However the threads you started from your foreground sticky service can still be killed by Android. I would try IntentService instead of starting new threads as its managed by Android, and very unlikely to be killed.

Comment: @rootkit Thanks for giving more info, will try that if I (god forbid it) ever come in the same situation again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using which runs without crashing or stalling:

```
System.gc();
startNewThreadAction();
```

This works but the main problem was that I had to jugle with this many threads. If you have the option between many threads and lots of data go for lots of data.

Comment: Running the GC this way does not guarantee that it'll run at that same moment. This is basically a hack to a bigger memory issue that you have. I suggest doing more research on that, trying to analyze the amount of threads you really need to invoke and maybe even change the way you download all that data.

Comment: @Udinic I know, and I aggree. But the project is out of my hands so can't do anything with it. If I had an a say, I'd change the way the data is downloaded. But out of my hands now.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you are hitting the limits of the number of threads the Android system can handle.
You mention you use an `ExecutorService`. By default only **5** Threads can run **at the same time**, and a **limit** of **128** Threads can be queued.

See the source code of the [AsyncTask](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/os/AsyncTask.java#AsyncTask)
The **CORE_POOL_SIZE** is the number of tasks that can run at the same time, the **MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE** is the amount of threads that can be queued.

Comment: Nice input, though I'm sure it was a memory issue since System.gc after each Runnable was done solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Running the GC is never a solution! it's just an indication to a bad code implementation.

You didn't supplied code but from the scenario you described you overflow the system with objects and data and that's why you need to call every now and then to the GC.

Make sure you reuse your object, for ex. - even though you are using threadPool - do you reuse the runnables or just creating a new runnable for every thread?

If you are using Task for example make sure to cancel and purge its TimerTask. The purge will clean all the ended tasks,

It isn't the thread concurrency that creates that problem since only 2 thread lives synchronously.

Comment: Didn't use Task. But didn't reuse my runnables even though it could've been done. Thanks for your pointers.